# Custom Map Styles Google Map / MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to achieve a Map design like the image below

[image]

I have achieved the design using **MapBox** though, its quite simple to get it done from it.

I have found Google Map can be easily customized from [here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

But I can't find a way to implement it in **iOS SDK** for **GoogleMaps**.

I highly want to use **GoogleMaps**, is there any way that I can achieve the map design above ?

Any help is appreciated..

Thanks.

Comment: Apple's MapKit can customize the map style, you can refer to the WWDC video this year. Do you have any particular reason to use Google Maps? Because from the image you showed in the question, I see no reason not using iOS SDK's MapKit to implement it.

Comment: @Jing No, any free service with styled map will do, thats why I choosed Google Map, thanks for the information about WWDC this year, I will check that out. For now I have managed to work with Google Maps Javascript, but it would have been better with SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Styled maps is currently not supported in the latest release of google maps SDK for iOS (v 1.5.0) but the ticket for this feature has been filed, so please go and star it to indicate your interest in this feature:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4968&q=apitype%3DIosSDK&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal